# Object relationships

Tags: soql, relationships, database

I have two objects Parent__c and Child__c, Child__c object have a lookup to Parent__c.
This code is clear to me, Child__c has a Parent__c field through which it can access to the Parent__r object:

```
[select id, Parent__r.name from Child__c]
```

And what is here? Does Parent__r have Childs__r field? How does Parent__r get access to the child object?

```
[select id, (select id from Childs__r) from Parent__c]
```

I am new in salesforce, please help me figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a lookup field, you specify the Child relationship name (and you can even change it later). For example, in the image [here[image: here]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9eN9.png), the name of the relationship is "Event_Seats".

So, when querying from the parent object (Opportunity) I can retrieve all seats by doing

```
SELECT Id, (Select Id, Name from Event_Seats__r) from Opportunity
```

And I can get the opportunity name from this Record by doing

```
SELECT Id, Associated_Opportunity__r.Name from Event_Seat__c
```

Comment: That is, when I create a lookup(Associated_Opportunity), I also create a field Event_Seats which is in father, which then helps him get to the child. Yes ?

Comment: There is no field per se. When you create the lookup, Salesforce automatically gets you access to the Children object via that relationship name. It's part of the "magic" of Salesforce, if you wish., In a way, it's the replacement for `INNER JOINS`.

Comment: The same is the situation with master-details ?

Comment: Exactly, works the same way